# Is possible to create a non-existent method when it is called in Python?

Tags: python

If I have this class:

```
class MyClass(object):
   pass
```

And then I do it:

```
instance = MyClass()
instance.new_method()
```

I got an AttributeError Exception, but I want to create this method dinamically and return an especifc value. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but there is likely a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you provide insight as to why you are trying to do this - what are your constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly Python checks if attribute with such name exists, if yes, it will call it. There's no clear way to prematurely detect whether this attribute will be called or not.

Here's the tricky way to achieve what you want:

```
class Dispatcher(object):

    def __init__(self, caller, name):
        self.name = name
        self.caller = caller

    def __call__(self, *a, **ka):
        print('Call on Dispatcher registered!', 
              'Will create method on',
              self.caller.__class__.__name__,
              'now.')
        setattr(self.caller, self.name, self.mock)
        return getattr(self.caller, self.name)(*a, **ka)

    @classmethod
    def mock(cls, *a, **ka):
        return 'Some default value for newly created methods.'


class MyClass(object):

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return Dispatcher(self, attr)


instance = MyClass()
print(instance.new_method, '\n')
print(instance.new_method(), '\n')
print(instance.new_method(), '\n')
print(instance.other_method)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Dispatcher object at 0x0000000002C07DD8> 

Call on Dispatcher registered! Will create method on MyClass now.
Some default value for newly created methods. 

Some default value for newly created methods. 

<__main__.Dispatcher object at 0x0000000002C07DD8>
```

Although this solution is comprehensive, it will return the new instance of `Dispatcher` every time you try to access non-existent attribute.

If `Dispatcher` instance is called (e.g `Dispatcher(self, attr)()`), it will set `mock` as a new method named `attr` to the object, passed as the first argument to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, do you know how to figure if what was called was a method or a attribute? Like, can I know if it was called instance.new_method or instance.new_method(). Because, the value of attr is the same =/

Comment: @rafaels88 do you need attribute or method?

Comment: I just need to get new methods, and create them. But, if it is an attribute, I do nothing.

Comment: @rafaels88 actually, when you're calling a method, Python firstly checks if it exist, and there's no simple and direct way to check whether it's attribute or method

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it as:

```
class MyClass(object):
   pass

def some_method():
    pass

name = 'new_method'    

setattr(MyClass, name, classmethod(some_method))
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this solution only sets the method as a function attribute. It does not, as the question requests, create the method when it is called.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
        pass

>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> def new_method(cls, x):
        print x


>>> MyClass.new_method = new_method
>>> instance.new_method(45)
45
```

Note that the `new_method` has `cls` as the first parameter which (the instance) is passed implicitly when called as an instance method.

Comment: Why `cls` instead of the usual `self`?

Comment: Normally I use `self` when method definitions are _inside_ the class definition. Here `new_method()` is an independent method. `instance` would be more appropriate though. Just a preference actually.

Comment: @mshayem. I only ask because `cls` is conventionally used when the instance is a class, as will class methods and `type.__new__`. Another reason to use `self` is that it may technically be passed in as a keyword, even if this is almost never actually done.